# Attempting to Solve Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I'm solving the velocity profile of a fluid flow and am having trouble figuring out how to approach the solution to the partial differential equation below for u(r,t).

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
 - \frac{\Delta p}{\rho L} e^{-i\omega t}
 = \mu \left(\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2}
           + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)u
$$

I know if the $\frac{\Delta p}{\rho L} e^{-i\omega t}$ term wasn't there I could use separation of variables, but I'm not sure how to get around that added term.

Comment: Solve the general homogeneous equation (ignoring the troublesome term) and then add a particular solution that gives you the troublesome term.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give that a try.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot!